# Haskell - Función con 2 condicionales y output de una tupla no devuelve valor correcto

Tags: lista, haskell

Tengo la siguiente función desarrollada en Haskell, la misma realiza un avg de 3 notas ingresadas y dependiendo la condición cuenta los elementos de la lista (utilizando length), el primer output de la tupla debería ser count(*) cuando la condición >= 4 y el segundo count(*) cuando es <4:

```
funcion1::[(String, Int,Int,Int)]->(Int,Int)
funcion1 ((nombre,nota1,nota2,nota3):xs) = ( if (nota1+nota2+nota3) `div` 3 >=4 then 1 + funcion1 xs else funcion1 xs ,
                                             if (nota1+nota2+nota3) `div` 3 <4 then 1 + funcion1 xs else funcion1 xs )
```

Sin embargo al ingresar datos en el input siempre la tupla devuelve los mismos valores para ambos casos (Ejemplo: Al ingresar 3 elementos con avg >= 4 y solo 1 con avg < 4 el output debería ser (3,1) y actualmente es (3,3).

Comment: En el _if/else_ siempre da el mismo resultado: `(length xs, length xs)`. Si introduces 4 elementos, siempre dará `(3, 3)`,

Comment: @ChemaCortes Claro, ese es mi problema pero no se como resolverlo para que resuelva bien la tupla y devuelva los 2 valores de output correspondientes, ya que son 2 condicionales distintos operando sobre la misma lista.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Una última consulta, si quisiera poner una palabra (String) delante del output de la tupla (a,b) tendría que agregarlo en el "where" también? Lo inserté en : funcion1 :: [(String, Int, Int, Int)] ->String->(Int, Int) pero no funcionó cuando lo agregué en el where.

Comment: Este comentario debería ir como comentario de la respuesta. Si es _output_, la signatura de la función no será `(Int, Int)`, sino algo como `(String, Int, Int)` o `(String, (Int, Int))`. Las funciones sólo tienen una única salida (y una única entrada).

Comment: @ChemaCortes Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enfocas mal el problema. En haskell no se usa tanto el *if/else* como en otros lenguajes. Cuando se trabaja con listas hay que pensar más en aplicar *filtros* (`filter`) y otras funciones que admiten predicados (lo que dices *condicionales*).

```hs
funcion1 :: [(String, Int, Int, Int)] -> (Int, Int)
funcion1 xs = (length $ filter (>=4) avgs, length $ filter (<4) avgs)
  where
    avg (_, nota1, nota2, nota3) = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) `div` 3
    avgs = map avg xs
```

Hemos creado la función `avg` que calcula la media y la hemos aplicado para obtener un listado de medias `avgs`. A este listado se aplican dos filtros, `(>=4)` y `(<4)`, para obtener las dos sublistas cuyas longitudes nos darán el conteo que buscamos.

Como los dos filtros son *excluyentes* (los elementos que cumplen un filtro no cumplen el otro), lo que tenemos realmente es una *partición* de la lista y podemos hacerlo algo más simple aplicando la funcion `partition` del módulo `Data.List`:

```hs
import Data.List (partition)

funcion1 :: [(String, Int, Int, Int)] -> (Int, Int)
funcion1 xs = ( (length . fst) part, (length . snd) part)
  where
    avg (_, nota1, nota2, nota3) = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) `div` 3
    avgs = map avg xs
    part = partition (>=4) avgs
```

Ya sólo falta dejarlo bonito creando una función `maptuple` para hacer un *map* en una tupla:

```hs
import Data.List (partition)

funcion1 :: [(String, Int, Int, Int)] -> (Int, Int)
funcion1 xs = maptuple length part
  where
    avg (_, nota1, nota2, nota3) = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) `div` 3
    avgs = map avg xs
    part = partition (>=4) avgs
    maptuple f (a,b) = (f a, f b)
```

Incluso más bonito aún, juntando todo:

```hs
import Data.List (partition)

funcion1 :: [(String, Int, Int, Int)] -> (Int, Int)
funcion1 = maptuple length . partition (>=4) . map avg
  where
    avg (_, nota1, nota2, nota3) = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3) `div` 3
    maptuple f (a,b) = (f a, f b)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ,muy clara y contundente tu explicación, ahora tengo  algunos conceptos más claros sobre listas y particiones.Saludos!